# How do I target an object with a specific variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object

I'm making an online game where users have different ID's.

Here's the client code for creating a new player:

```
var newPlayer = function(id){
   return player[player.length]={
      x:0,
      y:0,
      id:id
   }
}
```

`newPlayer(50)` would create a player with the ID 50.

How do I select that player based on its `id` variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function, iterate the array, return once found

```
function findPlayer(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
        if (player[i].id == id) return player[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The storage of a JavaScript array can be sparse so you can just do the following:

```
function newPlayer(id) {
  return player[id] = { x:0, y: 0, id: id };
}

function findPlayer(id) {
  return player[id];
}
```

This results in a at worst, *O(log N)*, but probably close to *O(1)*, lookup at the cost of potentially more storage.

Chuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = [];
newPlayer(123);
newPlayer(234);
```

Using Underscore or Lodash (or vanilla JS, if you prefer):

```
var player123 = _.findWhere(players, { id: 123 });
```

Etc.

If you will only ever search by id, and id is unique among all players, you could store the players in a key-value object instead of an array:

```
function newPlayer(id) {
    player[id] = { x: 0, id: id }
}
```

Lookup via:

```
var player123 = player[123];
```